# Authenticating to multiple services in Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight-5.0, restsharp

I have the following scenario:

1. A WCF Service on the same site as the Silverlight app (call this the "data service")
2. The website that the WCF service and Silverlight host page sits in is protected with Form Authentication
3. The WCF Service is in a folder that allows anonymous access
4. The Silverlight hosting page is in a folder that does NOT allow anonymous access
5. When the user logs in through forms authentication, the Silverlight app becomes accessible and when the WCF / data service is called, the forms authentication user is seen by the WCF service correctly.

Overall, this setup works great. However, we're calling a third-party REST service that requires basic authentication and we're using RestSharp to call that service. An example of that code is:

```
Dim url As String = ServicePrefix & ServiceBaseAddress
Dim client As New RestSharp.RestClient(url)
client.Authenticator = New HttpBasicAuthenticator(AccountSID, AuthToken)
Dim request As New RestSharp.RestRequest("Accounts/" & AccountSID & "/SMS/Messages.xml", RestSharp.Method.POST)
request.AddParameter("From", fromPhone)
request.AddParameter("To", toPhone)
request.AddParameter("Body", message)

syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current
Dim ia = client.ExecuteAsync(request, AddressOf HandleSMSResponse)
```

After the call to the third-party service returns successfully, and our message gets sent, Silverlight no longer sends the correct user in the HttpContext, so the WCF service doesn't identify the forms authentication user any more.

Our current thinking is that RestSharp is taking control of something is shouldn't be or isn't restoring state properly. Does anyone know where the security credentials are stored in Silverlight so we can grab them before the RestSharp call and restore them afterwards?

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Chirp* *chirp* the crickets are loud in here.

In any case, the solution we finally came up with was to move all of the calls to the third-part REST service into our own service. This kept Silverlight from loosing its credentials to our service (since we never call another service, from Silverlight).

I hope this helps someone who stumbles on this, someday.